# How to display API data in cards (Image, Name, Detail)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created API using node.js and want to display the data in card. Though data fetched, but image doesn't show and all data(all the name, price etc.) are showed in one card. How to solve it?

```
<Slider {...settings}>
  {products.map((popularObject, i) => (
    <li key={popularObject._id}>
      <div className="card-wrapper">
        <ul className="product">
          <div className="card">
            <Link to={"/product/" + popularObject._id}>
              <img
                className="card-image"
                src={
                  typeof popularObject.popular == "object" ? (
                    <div>
                      {popularObject.popular.map((subpopularObject, index) => {
                        <div key={index}>{subpopularObject.imageUrl}</div>;
                      })}
                    </div>
                  ) : null
                }
                alt="popular"
              />
            </Link>

            <div className="details">
              <div className="job-title">
                <h4>
                  <p className="tag">Radhunir Rannaghor</p>
                  <Link to={"/product/" + popularObject._id}>
                    {typeof popularObject.popular == "object" ? (
                      <div>
                        {popularObject.popular.map((subpopularobj, index) => (
                          <div key={index}>{subpopularobj.name}</div>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </Link>
                  <span className="job-title"></span>{" "}
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div className="job-title-price">
                {" "}
                <h4> ${popularObject.popular[i].price}</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  ))}
</Slider>
```

**Data:**

```js
{
products: [
    {
    popular: [
        {
          _id: "1", name: "Nasi Goreng", imageUrl: "imagestest/3.jpg", rating: "5.0", deliveryTime: "45 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Extra special", }, {
          _id: "2", name: "Rendang", imageUrl: "imagestest/7.jpg", rating: "4.9", deliveryTime: "35 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "250", note: "Special", }, {
          _id: "3", name: "Nasi Padang", imageUrl: "imagestest/16.jpg", rating: "4.5", deliveryTime: "55 mins", deliveryCharges: "Delivery charges 50 extra", price: "199", note: "Chilly", }, {
          _id: "7", name: "Pece", imageUrl: "imagestest/13.jpg", rating: "4.0", deliveryTime: "75 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Special, Spicy", }, {
          _id: "4", name: "Indomie", imageUrl: "imagestest/13.jpg", rating: "3.8", deliveryTime: "25 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Special, Spicy", }, ], 
    recommended: [
        {
          _id: "2", name: "Rendang", imageUrl: "imagestest/7.jpg", rating: "4.9", deliveryTime: "35 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "250", note: "Special", }, {
          _id: "1", name: "Nasi Goreng", imageUrl: "imagestest/3.jpg", rating: "5.0", deliveryTime: "45 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Extra special", }, {
          _id: "7", name: "Pece", imageUrl: "imagestest/13.jpg", rating: "4.0", deliveryTime: "75 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Special, Spicy", }, ], 
    allmenu: [
        {
          _id: "1", name: "Nasi Goreng", imageUrl: "imagestest/3.jpg", rating: "5.0", deliveryTime: "45 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Extra special", }, {
          _id: "2", name: "Rendang", imageUrl: "imagestest/4.jpg", rating: "4.9", deliveryTime: "35 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "250", note: "Special", }, {
          _id: "3", name: "Nasi Padang", imageUrl: "imagestest/6.jpg", rating: "4.5", deliveryTime: "55 mins", deliveryCharges: "Delivery charges 50 extra", price: "199", note: "Chilly", }, {
          _id: "4", name: "Indomie", imageUrl: "imagestest/12.jpg", rating: "3.8", deliveryTime: "25 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Special, Spicy", }, {
          _id: "5", name: "Rendang", imageUrl: "imagestest/6.jpg", rating: "4.9", deliveryTime: "35 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "250", note: "Special", }, {
          _id: "6", name: "Nasi Goreng", imageUrl: "imagestest/7.jpg", rating: "5.0", deliveryTime: "45 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "250", note: "", }, {
          _id: "7", name: "Pece", imageUrl: "imagestest/1.jpg", rating: "4.0", deliveryTime: "75 mins", deliveryCharges: "Free Delivery", price: "150", note: "Special, Spicy", }, ], }, ], };
```

Output on screen:

[No image in card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUWbK.jpg)

[All data in one card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfy7x.jpg)

Comment: Where did you import `Slider` from? What `Card` are you talking about? And here is how `products[0].popular.map` you need to use `map()` function on "popular".

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
{products.popular !== undefined ? products.popular.map((popularObject, index) => (

 <li key={popularObject._id}>
      <div className="card-wrapper">
        <ul className="product">
          <div className="card">
            <Link to={"/product/" + popularObject._id}>
              <img
                className="card-image"
                src={               
                       {popularObject.imageUrl}
                    
                }
                alt="popular"
              />
            </Link>

            <div className="details">
              <div className="job-title">
                <h4>
                  <p className="tag">Radhunir Rannaghor</p>
                  <Link to={"/product/" + popularObject._id}>
                   
                          <div key={index}>{popularObject.name}</div>
                 
                      </div>
                   
                  </Link>
                  <span className="job-title"></span>{" "}
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div className="job-title-price">
                <h4> ${popularObject.price}</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
): null }
```